# How can I dealloc and release these variables in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

Please see following code I want to know how can I **de-alloc cell** . From what I have understood there must be a de-alloc for every alloc and release for every retain.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UITableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                 reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    return cell;
}
```

and from the code below am I doing the right thing to **de-alloc the dataArray** or should it be release or both. 
**Interface**

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *dataArray;
}

@property(retain,nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;
@end
```

**From Implementation**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dataArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"XXX",@"YYY",@"ZZZ",nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self.dataArray dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the cell you allocated will be autoreleased because you have sent the object the autorelease message. So you don't need to worry about its memory being freed - that will happen automatically.

As to your second question, in general, you should not call dealloc directly. The system calls dealloc for you when an object's retain count goes to zero. You should read the following article which does a good job of explaining memory management in a very clear way: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/.

The specific code you posted has two problems. First, based on what I said above, the dealloc should be replaced with a call to release. Second, you actually have a memory leak: when you alloc the dataArray object, it gets a retain count of 1. But you assign it to a property defined with the "retain" attribute. So the setter for that property will retain the object again, taking its retain count to 2. When you finally release, it will go back down to 1, but not to zero, so it won't be released.

To fix this, instead of assigning the alloc'd object to the property, assign it to the instance variable backing the property. By default, the instance variable will have the same name as the property, so you just do

```
dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"XXX",@"YYY",@"ZZZ",nil];
```

If you explicitly gave the instance variable a name when you synthesized the property (by doing something like `@synthesize dataArray = _dataArray`, then use that name.

Another option you have is to not alloc/init the array but rather to use the [arrayWithObjects class method on NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray). The object you get back from that will be autoreleased, so you don't have to worry about managing it.

Answer (score 3):

> From what I have understood there must be a de-alloc for every alloc
>   and release for every retain.

You understand incorrectly.  There must be a release for every retain, but you do not/should not explicitly deallocate anything.

When you need an object you should retain it (and [[XX alloc]init] performs an initial retain for you).  When you no longer need an object you should release the retain you have on it.

Those are the simple rules.  There's not much fine print, but there are a number of features of the language that help you accomplish the rules, and a few "tricks of the trade" to learn (most notably how "autorelease" works).

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you don't have to worry about releasing that cell, because it will be released by the TableView, the tableView is really only retaining a fixed small amount of cells that reuses every time.

for the second example just use the convenience method that returns an autoreleased object:

```
self.dataArray = [NSArray initwithObject:myObject];
```

since you are using a retain setter the retain count will be 1 at the end, and this should be released in the dealloc method like this:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [dataArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You should not call dealloc directly on viewDidUnload, what you need to do here is for any retained subView of the mainView release it using the setter like so:

```
self.myView = nil;
```

This will release the previous value and point to nil.